# Transpose a summary table

Tags: r

I have a table with the following format in a text file:

[image]

And I need to transpose it so it looks like that:

[image]

Is there a simple way of doing this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
 df1%>%
    spread(species,count)%>%
    rbind(c(status="Total",colSums(.[-1])))
  status  A B  C
1  Alive 37 6 13
2   Dead 17 0 11
3  Total 54 6 24
```

To keep the class as numeric, you can do:

```
 df1%>%
     spread(species,count)%>%
     rbind(cbind.data.frame(status="Total",t(colSums(.[-1]))))
  status  A B  C
1  Alive 37 6 13
2   Dead 17 0 11
3  Total 54 6 24
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `reshape2::dcast` and `dplyr::summarise_at` can be achieved by changing data in `wide-format` and then binding with summary rows to include `Total`. The solution will be as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, status~species, value.var = "count") %>%
  bind_rows(c(status = "Total",summarise_at(.,vars(A:C), funs(sum))))

#   status  A B  C
# 1  Alive 37 6 13
# 2   Dead 17 0 11
# 3  Total 54 6 24
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
species status count
A Dead 17
A Alive 37
B Dead 0
B Alive 6
C Dead 11
C Alive 13",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `xtabs` with `addmargins` from `base R`

```
addmargins(xtabs(count  ~ status + species, df), 1)
#       species
#status   A  B  C
#  Alive 37  6 13
#  Dead  17  0 11
#  Sum   54  6 24
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(species = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
 status = c("Dead", 
 "Alive", "Dead", "Alive", "Dead", "Alive"), count = c(17L, 37L, 
 0L, 6L, 11L, 13L)), .Names = c("species", "status", "count"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```